# yarn workspaces - Can't resolve 'agrostar-styled-components'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, yarnpkg

I am trying out workspaces in yarn

Followed below steps

1. Turn on workspaces in yarn -yarn config set workspaces-experimental true
2. package.json in top level - "workspaces":["src/utilities/styled"]
3. Run - yarn start

Error - yarn workspaces -  Can't resolve 'agrostar-styled-components'

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Do you know what package or module of yours uses the "agrostar-styled-components" package?

Comment: yes, the top level package uses "agrostar-styled-components" package. But how does that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is I forgot to add dependency of "agrostar-styled-components" in package.json(Top level). And run -

> yarn install

It worked.